# Jenkins: writing to Global Parameters

Tags: android, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins, increment

Is there a way in Jenkins to not only read but also write global parameters from a job?
To achieve reading I used this plugin: [Global Variable String Parameter](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Global+Variable+String+Parameter+Plugin)
However, I have found nothing yet to support write access to global parameters. I see that this could be seen critical as it can create race conditions.

What I actually want to do:

I have two Jenkins Jobs - each publishing my Android APK to the Google Play Store but into different release tracks (e.g. "release" and "beta").

I want the build number to be incremented automatically via gradle. But gradle needs to access the build number of the last build from anywhere outside of my VCS (to avoid requiring another commit). I want to guarantee that the build numbers are chronologically in order. Hence, keeping a separate build number for every Jenkins Job (e.g. in a "version.properties" file) is not a solution.

A plan B could be to switch to a date encoded build number. But I'm curious if there is a way for the incremental approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use "version.properties" file located in the jenkins workspace and not the job workspace.

1- inject environment variable from the file

[image]

2- build the apk

3- increment the version from the shell script

> version=$(($version+1))
>
> echo version=$version > ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/module.properties

Comment: Do I just put the file on the file system of my jenkins server? Or can I configure the global "version.properties" within jenkins so it scales in case of multiple nodes?

Comment: yes you have to put the file on the file system, unfortunately this solution works only if you don't use nodes because they will not share the same workspace.

Comment: thanks for clarifying. The reason Jenkins does not support global writable variables, might be synchronisation issues and race conditions.